# Java custom implode methode like in PHP

Tags: java, string, format, implode

I am trying to replicate the php function implode() in Java.

This is what I made:

```
private String implode(String delimiter, Map<String, String> map){

   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   for(Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet()){
      sb.append(" "+delimiter+" ");
      sb.append(" " + e.getKey() + " = '" + e.getValue() + "' ");
   }

   return sb.toString();
}
```

Testing:

```
Map<String, String> myList = new HashMap<String, String>();
myList.put("address", "something1");
myList.put("last_name", "something2");
myList.put("first_name", "something3");

update_database("dummy", myList, "");

public void update_database(String table, Map<String, String> update_list, String condition){
   String query = "UPDATE " + table + " SET ";

   query += implode(",", update_list) + " " + condition;

    System.out.println(query);
}
```

Output:

> UPDATE dummy SET , address = 'something' , last_name = 'something2',
>   first_name = 'something3'

If you worked with mysql before, you know that it's not a valid query because the string query start with ",".

How can I format my string to get a correct query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try something like this:

**Own Implementation**

```
private String implode(String delimiter, Map<String, String> map){

   boolean first = true;
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   for(Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet()){
      if (!first) sb.append(" "+delimiter+" ");
      sb.append(" " + e.getKey() + " = '" + e.getValue() + "' ");
      first = false;
   }

   return sb.toString();
}
```

**StringUtils**

Another solution would be to use [public static String join(Collection collection, char separator)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#join%28java.util.Collection,%20char%29)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to write this yourself.  [There's already a library with this functionality named guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) made by google.  [It has a class called a Joiner](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html).  Here's an example:

```
Joiner joiner = Joiner.on("; ").skipNulls();
return joiner.join("Harry", null, "Ron", "Hermione");
```

This returns the string "Harry; Ron; Hermione". Note that all input elements are converted to strings using Object.toString() before being appended.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to import an entire library for one functions of one class of that library.

Comment: @Achshar because I don't want to think (or fail to think) about all the edge cases.  I think DRY violations are worse than the extra space of the library.